# Correctly Writing a Range Based Constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, c++14

I had a question to do with writing a range based constructor for a class but couldn't find the right phrasing to search for help on google.

Suppose I am writing a simple class, like vector, which involves having a range based constructor that inserts elements from the range into the current container:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    template<class InputIterator> Foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
        std::cout << "Range based constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(size_t n, int val) {
        std::cout << "size_t, int constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

};

#endif // FOO_H
```

and have a cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "foo.h"

using std::cout;    using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(10, 5);
    Foo f_default;
    Foo f_range(v.begin(), v.end());   
    Foo f_int(314, 159);       // want this to call size_t, int ctctr
    return 0;
}
```

In the third line in main, we create a `Foo f_int(314, 159)` which intuitively we want to call the size_t, int constructor. However it is matching the generic template constructor for ranges instead. Is there a way issues like this are addressed in C++? I feel like I am incorrectly dealing with writing range based constructors.

I can imagine you can use template specialization maybe, but don't really see how.

An example where such a situation might happen is if we are writing a vector class where there is a constructor based on a size_t and default value (which would be templatised on the class but I simplified here) and another constructor based on iterator ranges.

Comment: `"hello"` and `"world"` will also match your templated constructor, and they are certainly not iterators either (they may be passed as pointers though).   `314` and `159` are both literals of type `int`, which is why they match.  Convert one of them to a different type, to stop matching the template (e.g. `Foo f_int((std::size_t)314, 519)`.  Don't convert both arguments, since that will also result in the template matching.

Comment: @Peter I know how to make it call the correct one; that is not my question. My question is how to implement the class correctly so that a client doesn't have to worry about the difference. When we use std::vector as `std::vector<int> v(10, 5)`, we don't makes sure to be careful by doing something like `std::vector<int> v((std::vector<int>::size_type)10, (int)5)`. We just call the constructor knowing it will call the right one.

Comment: You'll need to provide a constructor that explicitly accepts two `int` arguments, so that will be preferred over the template.   When given two arguments of type `int`, the standard requires that a template like yours be preferred over any other constructor that relies on an implicit conversion.

Comment: @gowrath `std::vector`'s iterator constructor had the same problem that you ran into. Notice the difference in wording of constructor (4)'s behavior [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you! That is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor template is a better match in the third case because you're passing two `int` arguments, while the `Foo(size_t n, int val)` requires an `int` to `size_t` conversion for the first argument. If you modify your code to

```
Foo f_int(static_cast<size_t>(314), 159);
```

the constructor you want is called. But of course, this is not a good solution because it's easy to accidentally call the wrong constructor. Instead, you can use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to drop the constructor template from the overload resolution set by ensuring the argument types are iterators.

```
template<class InputIterator,
         class = std::enable_if_t<
                    std::is_base_of<
                        std::input_iterator_tag,
                        typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category
                    >{}
                >
        >
Foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    std::cout << "Range based constructor called" << std::endl;
}
```

If you look at the table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), all iterators you can read from are *InputIterators* or derived types. So the code above is checking that the `InputIterator` type being passed to the constructor is of that type or something derived from that type.